# Is there something like gnome-keyring for Windows7?

Tags: windows, security, password-management

I want to use my login password to autounlock a passwordmanager. Is there something which makes this possible and fairly secure?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442923/windows-equivalent-of-os-x-keychain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "password manager" can mean two slightly different programs.

- If you are looking for a database where *you* can keep your own information, check out [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) – it has an option to protect the database using your Windows user account. (This feature is only available in the 2.x series, though.)

  - Technically, *any* software can be made to work in a similar way, if you use the "Encrypted File System" (EFS) feature in Windows. (Win 7 has it starting with Professional.) All files you encrypt using EFS are encrypted with a certificate which is in turn protected with your Windows password. (Make sure you back up the certificate *and* the private key; Windows 7 should prompt you to do this.)

    This means you can create a database using Password Safe or KeePass or Notepad *without* any password, only encrypted using EFS, and it will be securely protected using your Windows password.
- GNOME Keyring is primarily intended to be used by *other programs*. In Windows, the same can be done using [Credentials API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374731(v=VS.85).aspx#credentials_management_functions): programs can store passwords through `CredRead()`/`CredWrite()` (in the form of CRED_TYPE_GENERIC), and you can browse the same entries through *Control Panel – Credentials*.